# How to deploy multiple applications in tomcat with the same port and change in context?

Tags: session

I want to deploy multiple web applications in my tomcat 8.5 server with the same port and different application context. So far by putting all the war in the Webapps directory, I am able to achieve that. Now the use case is one of those application needs to be deployed on 80 port while others will be on 8080 port.

So the set looks like:

http://x.x.x.x:8080/xyz

http://x.x.x.x:8080/abc

http://x.x.x.x:8080/foo

http://x.x.x.x/bar

Now there is a link in /xyz application which redirects to /bar application and these two should share the session between them, otherwise, the link in /xyz application is redirecting to login page.

My query is whether I need to configure anything at tomcat level in order to achieve that. Note that my applications are built on top of Spring MVC

Answer (score 1):

Use context docbase as mentioned below

```
<Context docBase="/your/path/app1" 
      path="/app1" reloadable="true" />


<Context docBase="/your/path/app2" 
      path="/app2" reloadable="true" />
```

Comment: Should I try this by moving the WARs to outside of webapps?

Comment: For port 80 to work you need to add proxy using apache web server. Tomcat cannotaccess port 80 directly